# Crashlytics Android NDK: externalNativeBuild DEBUG crash symbolication works RELEASE not

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Crashes in C++ code are working for Debug builds in Crashlytics but not for Release builds. It looks like that there is nothing uploaded/generated on crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease (takes only seconds). Debug takes about 7 minutes to generate.

I already deleted build and .externalNativeBuild directories. Anyone has a hint where to problem comes from?

Here is the config and the logs:

```
build.gradle:

afterEvaluate {
    dexguardRelease.logging.level = 'INFO'
    assembleDebug.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug)
    assembleBeta.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsBeta)
    assembleRelease.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease)
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}

Debug Build

Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 7 mins 9.074 secs.
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug' into context took 0.001 secs.
Executing task ':app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 13.225 secs.
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug' into context took 0.001 secs.
Executing task ':app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.802 secs) due to:
  No history is available.
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 1 mins 16.179 secs.
:kerneldjinni:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) started.
:kerneldjinni:extractDebugAnnotations
Putting task artifact state for task ':kerneldjinni:extractDebugAnnotations' into context took 0.0 secs.
file or directory '/Users/mschicker/OutBankGIT/outbankandroid/sitbankingkernel/Android/kerneldjinni/src/debug/java', not found
Executing task ':kerneldjinni:extractDebugAnnotations' (up-to-date check took 0.014 secs) due to:
  Output property 'destinationDir' file /Users/mschicker/OutBankGIT/outbankandroid/sitbankingkernel/Android/kerneldjinni/build/intermediates/annotations/debug has changed.
  Output property 'typedefFile' file /Users/mschicker/OutBankGIT/outbankandroid/sitbankingkernel/Android/kerneldjinni/build/intermediates/typedefs.txt has changed.
:kerneldjinni:extractDebugAnnotations (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.022 secs.
:kerneldjinni:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 6,5,main]) started.
:kerneldjinni:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':kerneldjinni:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug' into context took 0.001 secs.



Release Build

:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease' (up-to-date check took 0.002 secs) due to:
  Output property '$1' file /Users/mschicker/OutBankGIT/outbankandroid/app/build/fabric/release/csyms has changed.
:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.126 secs.
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsRelease
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsRelease' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsRelease' as it is up-to-date (took 0.0 secs).
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease' as it is up-to-date (took 0.0 secs).
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
```

Comment: What version of gradle and what version of Crashlytics are you using?

Comment: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0, 
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.1, gradle 3.0.1

Comment: Thanks, those are the new Crashlytics SDK versions so that looks right. You might want to email into support@fabric.io so the team can help solve this one. NDK issues can be tricky and we generally need log information and more details about your setup.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue myself. The cmake files had a rule to replace "-g"

```
string(REPLACE "-g" "" CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})
string(REPLACE "-g" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
string(REPLACE "-g" "" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE})
string(REPLACE "-g" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
```

This caused the missing symbols.